# CheckMenuItem problem in pygtk trayicon program

Tags: python, menu, checkbox, pygtk, trayicon

I have the following python (pygtk) program. When I move the mouse over the menu displayed, if clicked on the item in the tray the check boxes become checked and immediately unchecked again. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import  gtk
import  glib
import  subprocess
import  time
import  sys



class StatusIcon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statusicon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.statusicon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_HOME) 
        self.statusicon.connect("popup-menu", self.right_click_event)



    def right_click_event(self, icon, button, time):
        """
        We show a menu
        """
        menu = gtk.Menu()

        submenu = gtk.Menu()
        menuitem    = gtk.MenuItem("1")
        submenu.append(menuitem)
        menuitem    = gtk.MenuItem("2")
        submenu.append(menuitem)

        lst = ["a","b","c"]

        for item in lst:
            newmenuitem = gtk.CheckMenuItem(str(item))
            newmenuitem.set_submenu(submenu)
            menu.append(newmenuitem)

        # Now add all other menu stuff
        menu.append(gtk.SeparatorMenuItem())
        menuexit    = gtk.CheckMenuItem("exit")
        menuexit.connect("button-press-event", self.exit)
        menu.append(menuexit)

        # Show the menu
        menu.show_all()
        menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu, button, time, self.statusicon)

    def exit(self, widget, event):
        """
        Menu exit pressed
        """
        if event.button == 1:   #LEFT
            print   "terminate"
            gtk.main_quit()


StatusIcon()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: PS: I tried it with Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04, in both cases it has this behavior!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submenu is "toggling" the state of the checkbox when it appears.  You can fight this behavior by handling the toggle signal of the checkbox menuitem.

```
class StatusIcon:

...

  def callback(self, widget, data=None):
    widget.set_active(False)

...

    for item in lst:
        newmenuitem = gtk.CheckMenuItem(str(item))
        newmenuitem.connect("toggled", self.callback, "")
```